# jQuery Mobile ListView items with Color Indicator

Tags: css, listview, jquery-mobile, listviewitem

I want to have color indicators for each item in the list view in jQuery Mobile. Not the background color. This might be a piece of cake for most of you but unfortunately, my CSS skills are not very good. Here is a photoshop of what I want to achieve.

[image]

According the jQuery mobile docs, the closet I can have is to have thumbnail or list icons by putting a `img` tag. How can I achieve it? Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try these CSS rules:

```
#redHero {
  border-left: 5px solid #f00;
}

#greenHero {
  border-left: 5px solid #0f0;
}
```

According to this code:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-theme="b">
    <li id="redHero"><h3>Superman</h3><p>Power:30</p></li>
    <li id="greenHero"><h3>Spiderman</h3><p>Power:30</p></li>
</ul>
```

See the example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/FyxBK/).